# White text on blue header is difficult to read

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

The design choice of having a vibrant blue on top of a slightly different vibrant blue at the header of the site and questions is very jarring and difficult to look at. As someone who spends a lot of time on StackExchange this is by far the worst and most jarring design choice I have seen and made me not want to stick around.

[image]

It seems that most of it is coming from the white text on the bright blue, maybe it is also the font choice? Typically when white text is used in Material Design is is a heavier weight font (yes I know Roboto was used here) and is used sparingly if at all on light vibrant backgrounds.

A slightly more subdued pair of blues, taken directly from the [Material Design Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette)  works much better and is less straining.

[image]

Something like this with #1976D2 for the upper background and #2196F3 for the question header strip:

[image]

Comment: How is it jarring?  The ligher-blue "box" behind the title text is not something you need to focus on, it doesn't need extreme constrast from its background.

Comment: @MatthewRead I guess it's mostly just that the colors are so vibrant with somewhat small white knockout text on them that it is hard to read/focus comfortably.  After spending a few seconds reading a question title it literally burns that blue into my vision even after I look away from the screen. Am I really the first person to have said this?

Comment: @MatthewRead You will also notice that in the Material Design guidelines they switch to the use of black text with this shade of blue and lighter shaded because of legibility issues.

Comment: Oh, if the text is the issue that's more understandable.  I don't personally find black text more readable with that background but it's certainly subjective.

Comment: Do you have something in mind? How about proposing the design (image) or an idea (image) you think *wouldn't be worst*? There is no concrete direction in the question as of now other than the fact that you dislike the current design.

Comment: @Firelord I added some screenshots. My main point was that the site is clearly trying to follow the Android/Material Design style, but is missing a bit by using the wrong color/white text pairing per what the guidelines describe.

Comment: @MattRockwell You're right! I too feel the same. The blue is lighter and white is obviously lighter color. Dark backgroudn on Light text or vice-versa could be nice. Anyway I'm always using my [Android Dark theme userstyle](https://userstyles.org/styles/116735/android-stackexchange-customized-darktheme) on my Chrome using the Stylish extension. You can try that but I've customized many other parts than just header so if know css, you can create you own custom css styling for any website you want. ;)

Comment: With my current settings on my monitor, I found it hard to notice the difference between current and proposed design, nor do I have issue with current design at all. I can only notice that it's darker/stronger than [metase] header. But again, I acknowledge that this is design issue and might be very subjective to each.

Comment: @AndrewT. Subjective or not, it is currently violating the Material Design guidelines. It's wrong. If the effort is going to be taken to design it so that it resembles the Android design, it shouldn't be sloppy/half done.